# Keycloak Kubernetes 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-security, keycloak, istio

I have a keycloak server and a spring boot app running on Kubernetes cluster and I'm facing 2 scenarios the first one is working and the other one I'm getting 401 Unauthorized.

First scenario:

- Enter a test container with kubectl exec command inside my k8s cluster and ask for a token with a curl POST request :
  http://keycloak-service-name:8080/auth/realms/lisa/protocol/openid-connect/token
- I get a token
- I send a request from postman using that token to the secured endpoint of my app and
  It's working, access is granted

Second scenario:

- Ask for a token by sending a POST request to: http://keycloak-external-ip:port/auth/realms/lisa/protocol/openid-connect/token with the necessary parameters from postman
- I receive an access token
- I send a request from postman to the secured endpoint using that token of my app I get 401 unauthorized

The Keycloak is exposed using NodePort service.

The app is exposed using istio ingress gateway.

Keycloak server version:9.0.0.

keycloak version in spring boot app: 10.0.2

Comment: Same here, a question was posted at [Keycloak forum](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/gettiing-401-when-access-from-outside-but-200-from-inside-a-k8s-container/4998).

Comment: Hi, can you add the following to your question?: 1. Details on the incoming request to the istio ingress gateway. 2. Details on the application behind the istio ingress gateway.
3. The logs of your istio ingress gateway.

Comment: this is a curl of the request I send through the istio gateway to test my app:curl --location --request GET 'http://gateway-external-ip/history/admin/v1/health' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=2C40C674EA1A3D13BEC98313BB3D23C6; JSESSIONID=B1CF761DA1349D2AF40F7DB11FBB2503' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer  token'

Comment: The issue is most likely related to JWT ISS checking failing for external call. It looks to me that it is configured based on local service/hostname. You can verify that by checking logs. Take a look at this github [post](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15122#issuecomment-505963324) to see how to view logs.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this by changing the keycloak.auth-server-url value in the application.properties file.
The keycloak deployment has 2 services, one of type clusterIP, the second is of type nodePort

before

`keycloak.auth-server-url=http://keycloak-clusterIP-service-name:8080/auth`

after

`keycloak.auth-server-url=http://node-ip-adress:nodePort/auth`